# JavaScript is not working on partial views retrieved from paging links

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following main view inside my asp.net MVC razor view engine:-

```
<div><span class="b"> There are @Model.TotalItemCount Virtual Machines.</span></div>
@Html.Partial("_PagedVMTable",Model)
<i class=" icon icon-blue icon-star-on "></i> IT360 Data
    @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#ServerSort").click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    url: "@Url.Action("Index","VirtualMachine")",

                    data: { searchTerm:  "@ViewBag.searchTerm.ToString()" , page:"1" , sort: "@ViewBag.ServerSortPam" },
                    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    //dataType: "json",
                    //cache: false,
                    success: successFunc,
                    error: errorFunc
                });

                function successFunc(data, status) {     
                    $("#VMTable").html(data);
                }

                function errorFunc() {
                    alert('error');
                }
            })
            $("#RackSort").click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    url: "@Url.Action("Index","VirtualMachine")",

                    data: { searchTerm: "@ViewBag.searchTerm.ToString()", page: "1", sort: "@ViewBag.RackSortPam" },
                    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    //dataType: "json",
                    //cache: false,
                    success: successFunc,
                    error: errorFunc
                });

        function successFunc(data, status) {
            $("#VMTable").html(data);
        }

        function errorFunc() {
            alert('error');
        }
    })
        });
    </script>

}
```

and the following part of the _PagedVMTAble partial view:-

```
 <th>
 <a id="ServerSort">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.ServerID)</a>
 </th>

 <th>
 <a id="RackSort">Rack  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.Server.Rack.Technology.Tag) </a>
 </th>
```

Now the javaScript will work fine when calling the main view, but after clicking on a paged link (which will update the partial view only) the javaScript will stop working. I mean by stop working is that when I click on the “RackSort” OR “ServerSort” links, nothing will happen?

So can anyone advice ?

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

**As you are modifying HTML**. You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on(event,selector,callback_function)
```

Example

```
$(document).on('click', "#ServerSort", function(){
    //Your code
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.